# Is $f: \mathbb R^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{2}$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

$\mathbb R^*$ is $\mathbb R/ \{ 0\}$ under the multiplication operation.

$f: \mathbb R^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{2}$ such that $f(r) = 0$ if $r>0$, and $f(r) = 1$ if $r<0$.  I think that $f$ is a homomorphism because:

For $r>0$:

$f(a \cdot b) = 0 = [f(a) + f(b)]_2 = [0+0]_2 = 0$ and
$f(-a \cdot -b) = 0 = [f(-a) + f(-b)]_2 = [1+1]_2 = 0$

For $r<0$

$f(-a \cdot b) = 1 = [f(-a)+f(b)]_2 = [1+0]_2 = 1$

Also, the kernel of $f$ be all $n \in R^*$ such that $n>0$. Is my logic correct?

Comment: Correct. Just it would be clearer if you declare that $a,b>0$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct.

However, as @AlanWang points out, it would be even better if you declared that $a,b>0$.